# Import httpclient.URI using httpclient 4.3.6

Tags: java, apache, http, httpclient

I am migrating from httpclient 3.x to 4.3.6.

I followed: http://debuguide.blogspot.in/2013/01/quick-guide-for-migration-of-commons.html

However, I am receiving this error:

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class URI
```

I tried to import URI class but

```
import org.apache.http.URI;
```

doesn't exist.

and now

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI;
```

no longer exist in the new jar file.

How should I make the following lines not cause an error:

```
URI url = new URI(someurl, false);
url.setPath(somepath);
Protocol protocol = new Protocol(url.getScheme(), socketFactory, url.getPort());
.....
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also post the surrounding code snippet where you the url object?  Is it something like HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost(url); ? In that case, you will have to import java.net.URI though I don't see a constructor with the signature you are using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#constructor_summary

Comment: @Nandana  It was using https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/URI.html  and using this constructor  public URI(String s, boolean escaped)

Comment: Looking at the new API, apparently new HTTP client uses java.net.URI now. So you can that class. If you want to URL encode before creating the URI, you can use URLCodec [1] from Commons Codec project [2].
[1] http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/URLCodec.html
[2] http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/

Comment: @Nandana I see. Just found out more things are deprecated in the latest version. Looks like I will have to look for more tutorials, thanks!

Comment: As there a big changes in the 4.x API, may be you can include few more lines to expand where the protocol is used etc.